# Spark: Complex operation with dataframes

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the input dataset in the following format:

```
+---+--------+----------+
| id|   refId| timestamp|
+---+--------+----------+
|  1|    null|1548944642|
|  1|29950529|1548937685|
|  2|27510720|1548944885|
|  2|27510720|1548943617|
+---+--------+----------+
```

A new column `session` needs to be added with the following transformation logic:

1. If `refId is null`, the session value is true.
2. If `id and refId are unique`, the session value is true.
3. If `id and refId are not unique` and `timestamp is greater than the previous row, the session value is true. Also the difference between the timestamps should be >60.

```
+---+--------+-------+----------+
| id|   refId|session| timestamp|
+---+--------+-------+----------+
|  1|    null|   true|1548944642|
|  1|29950529|   true|1548937685|
|  2|27510720|  false|1548943617|
|  2|27510720|   true|1548944885|
+---+--------+-------+----------+
```

I am able to do 1 & 3 conditions separately but not the 2nd one.

1. `data.withColumn("session", functions.when(data.col("refId").isNull(), true));
  3.

```
WindowSpec w = Window.partitionBy("id, refid").orderBy(timestampDS.col("timestamp"));
functions.coalesce(timestampDS.col("timestamp").cast("long").$minus(functions.lag("timestamp", 1).over(w).cast("long")), functions.lit(0));
```

My question is how to fulfill 2nd condition and implement all 3 transformations together.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use Spark SQL for less complexity and achieve your result easily

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")

spark.sql("select id,refId,timestamp,case when refId is null and id is not null then 'true' when id is not null and refId is not null and rank=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as session from  (select id,refId,timestamp, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id,refId ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as rank from test) c").show()
```

The output looks like this  :

```
+---+--------+----------+-------+
| id|   refId| timestamp|session|
+---+--------+----------+-------+
|  1|    null|1548944642|   true|
|  1|29950529|1548937685|   true|
|  2|27510720|1548944885|   true|
|  2|27510720|1548943617|  false|
+---+--------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Like the spark sql implementation. How would I check the difference between the timestamps with same `id` and `refId`?

Comment: The rank is based on the Timestamp Only. So the latest timestamp will always get the Rank = 1 for same id and ref id.

Answer (score 1):

you can use window function to groupBy id and rfId and order by timestamp then add a rank column. Finally you add the session column with the when, otherwise sql function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, col, rank, lit, lag}
val win = Window.partitionBy("id", "refId").orderBy("timestamp")
val result = df
      .withColumn("previous", lag("timestamp", 1) over win)
      .withColumn("rank", rank() over win)
      .withColumn("session",
        when(col("refId").isNull || col("rank") === lit(1), true)
          .otherwise(false)
      )
      .withColumn("diff", col("timestamp") - col("previous"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to check the difference between the timestamps of the previous row and current row? The difference should be > 60.

Comment: yes, you can use the sql function lag to create a column that contains prebvous timestamp and then calculate the diff between the columns
df.withColumn("lag", lag('id, 1) over windowSpec)

Comment: How would it work with the `rank` column? Do you mind updating the code?

Comment: I've just upddated

Comment: does it check if the difference is greater than 60?

Comment: you can compare the diff with 60 if you want. Just add
.withColumn("diff60", col("timestamp") - col("previous") > 60)

Comment: Thanks. I will test the logic in a few minutes.

Comment: Stuck with this issue with the same `refId`s. Here the eralier timestamp is getting to set as true.`|| col("rank") === lit(1), true`